# How to use Klepto package Python

Tags: python, directory, pickle, archive, klepto

Hellow World!

I have a pickle file (containing images in byte form) to open but when I open it with pickle I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "test.py", line 10, in main
    dump = pickle.load(file)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I was told to use klepto instead. This is my try at it but when I load and try to print the data it prints "None"

```
localdb = dir_archive('E:\localdb', {}, serialized=True, cached=True)
print(localdb)
d = localdb.load('K_Select all images with a construction vehicle\output.pkl')
print(d)
```

and this is the output:

```
dir_archive('localdb', {}, cached=True)
None
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated